# How to install Xposed on S6

Tags: rooting, root-access, samsung, twrp, xposed-framework

I rooted my EE Samsung S6 (SM-G920F) (UK) (Marshmallow 6.0.1) yesterday evening using Odin (I followed the tutorial on [Tom's Guide](http://www.tomsguide.com/us/samsung-galaxy-s6-guide,review-2856-3.html)). I seemed to root fine. There was no bricking, boot looping or any other errors, and SuperSU installed as well.

It came to this morning when I decided to install Xposed (I don't want a custom ROM because Marshmallow is beautiful enough). I downloaded TWRP first from the Play Store, and installed the boot thingy from the app using 'Samsung Galaxy S6' as the device name, and 'twrp-3.0.2-1-zeroflte.img' as the recovery version. This installed fine, and if I booted in recovery, it went onto the TWRP interface.

I then **downloaded** the [Xposed Framework .zip](http://dl-xda.xposed.info/framework/sdk23/arm64/) (from the [XDA Forums](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=3034811)) and the [Xposed Installer](http://www.apkmirror.com/apk/rovo89/xposed-installer/xposed-installer-3-0-release/xposed-installer-3-0-alpha4-2-android-apk-download/) (It had to be from a mirror because the link from the forums had been deleted). I DID NOT **INSTALL** OR UNZIP THE FILES!!!

I then flashed the .zip by booting into TWRP recovery. My device now does not turn on. It just stays on the breathing Samsung logo, with the blue notification LED on.

I can uninstall the framework by running the device in recovery again and flashing the uninstall .zip, which does fix the device.

So, how do I install Xposed Framework and Installer? Please provide links if needed.

Thanks :))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's exactly the same for me. Except my device do not want to boot in recovery mode. How did you do this? Because I'm stuck on the black screen and blue LED.

Edit: There was an issue and I needed to flash again TWRP with Odin and sideload  Xposed uninstaller.

Edit 2: Solution
As it say on xda forum "Bootloops on Samsung stock ROMs. That's due to Samsung's changes to ART. There are unofficial builds that work around this by deodexing and adjusting the ROM." So we need a deodexed rom: [XtreStoLite 3.3.1 FINAL Marshmallow Android 6.0.](http://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-s6/development/rom-xtrestolite-deodexed-mod-edition-1-0-t3094423)1 for example. Still, Xposed will no work because the official version do not support Samsung S6. There is an unoficial version for S6 [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/xposed/unofficial-xposed-samsung-lollipop-t3180960). It worked for me.